# Adding to List<Model> using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel with a parameter List.  In the View, the user should be able to add or remove from that list such that the added or removed users are reflected in the POST for that parameter. In JQuery, after clicking an "Add" button, an ajax call returns a UserModel variable, but a simple .append doesn't add to the list.

The other questions I've seen on this issue deal with Partial Views, but this situation updates the table of UserModel without needing a Partial View.  It seems like there should be an easy way to do this. Does anyone know how to add the returned UserModel to the List in JQuery so that the List will be returned to the Post with the added models?

```
<script>
    $("#bUser").on('click', function () {
            var $addedRecipient = $("#AddedRecipient");
            if ($addedRecipient.val() != null && $addedRecipient.val() != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetFullRecipient", "Message")',
                    data: { CompanyID: $("#CompanyID").val(), Employee: $addedRecipient.val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#Recipients").append(data);//Not adding to Recipients (Model.List<UserModel>) - is there a simple solution like this?
                        var bRow = $('<tr></tr>'),
                            bCell = $('<td style="display:none"></td>').append(data.UserID);
                        bRow.append(bCell);
                        bCell = $('<td align="center"></td>').append(data.UserFirstName);
                        bRow.append(bCell);
                        bCell = $('<td align="center"></td>').append(data.UserEmail);
                        bRow.append(bCell);
                        bCell = $('<td align="center"><input type="button" class="btn btn-info removeRecipient" value="Remove"></td>');
                        bRow.append(bCell);
                        $("#bTable tbody").append(bRow);//Works with returned data
                        $addedRecipient.val("");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Recipient could not be added.");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: `returns a UserModel variable` can you elaborate on how you return this?  Are you returning it as JSON?  What do you get in the `success:` callback?  `success: function (data) { console.log(data); }`

Comment: `$("#Recipients").append(data);` - if `data` is HTML then this will work - if it's JSON, then no, that makes no sense as `.append` needs HTML.  This is why other suggestions for asp.net-mvc return a partial view - ie an HTML string.  If you're just returning an "object" how would you expect that to be converted to HTML?   Especially as your HTML appears to be a table, what if you change it to a div-layout?  How would it know?  If you want to return an object you'll have to build the HTML yourself.

Comment: If the problem is that when you POST you're not getting it added to your action's model (as implied by the "not adding to `Model.List<>`" which make no sense for javascript/jquery), then that's a whole different problem.

Comment: @freedomn-m I added an edit to reflect your third comment.  The issue is not display, as the table of users displays new added entries, but the POST does not contain those added user entries in the List parameter.

Comment: Ok, depends on how your action is defined and how you are rendering the original table.  Most likely it's creating inputs with names like `<input type="hidden"  name="userid[0]"/><input type="hidden"  name="userid[1]"/>`  - these **must** be sequential.  When you add your new row, add with the next available number `name="userid[2]"` then it will bind correctly (assuming action sig is correct).  Have a read of https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks very much!  I'll have a read and implement the changes.  I'll provide an update when completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here followed the link in freedomn-m's comment.  Iterate through the Razor table using a for loop, then use a HiddenFor with the model parameter's ID and a CheckBoxFor as the model parameter's selecting field, and have a submit button with a unique name and value.  When a button input is clicked and the value fits a given string, loop through the model and add a user that's not there or subtract a user that is there and return to the View.

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12">
         <table class="table table-bordered" id="bTable">
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th style="display:none"></th>
                     <th style="display:none"></th>
                     <th class="text-center">Recipient</th>
                     <th class="text-center">E-mail</th>
                     <th class="text-center">Select</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 @if (Model.Recipients.Any())
                 {
                     for (var i = 0; i < Model.Recipients.Count; i++)
                     {
                         <tr>
                             <td style="display:none">@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Recipients[i].RecipientUserID)</td>
                             <td style="display:none">@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Recipients[i].RecipientCorporateID)</td>
                             <td align="center">@Model.Recipients[i].RecipientName</td>
                             <td align="center">@Model.Recipients[i].RecipientEmail</td>
                             <td align="center">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Recipients[i].RemoveRecipient)</td>
                         </tr>
                     }
                 }
             </tbody>
         </table>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code worked perfect for me, you just have to go through this list, obviously you have to put the @model directive and  a type list Recipient.

```
@model List<...Models.Recipient>    
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" 
     onclick="myfunction()"/>

        <script>

        function myfunction() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetFullRecipient","Message")',
                data: { CompanyID: $("#CompanyID").val(), Employee: 
                $addedRecipient.val()},
                success: function (response) {  

                    $("#containerData").html(response);          
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        }

    </script>



    <div id="containerData"> 

      <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Desc_Prod</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>



            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @if (Model != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.UserID</td>
                        <td>@item.UserFirstName</td>
                        <td>@item.UserEmail</td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="@Url.Action("DeleteRow","Message", new {item.UserID})">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>

                }


            }

        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I added an edit to clarify the question.  The display updates the table with any new added users, but the POST back to the controller does not contain any added users in the List parameter.  Will this answer accomplish that?